# datatable: click on the line, the line will not close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a row that I have defined it this way:

```
  oTable = $('#archivio').dataTable({
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bAutoWidth": true,
    "sScrollY": 440,
    "bScrollCollapse": true,
    "sDom": '<"top"f>rt',
    "fnDrawCallback": function () {
        $('#archivio tbody tr').hover(function () {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'pointer');
        }, function () {
            $(this).css('cursor', 'auto');
        });
    }
});
```

and I have defined a function to click on the line that opens or closes an informative part of it :

```
$("#archivio tbody tr").click(function (e) {              

    var nTr = $(this)[0];
    var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nTr);

    $(oTable.fnGetNodes()).each(function () {      
        var nTr1 = $(this)[0];                          
        var aData1 = oTable.fnGetData(nTr1); 
        if (aData[1] != aData1[1]) {                     
            $(this).removeClass('active');            
            oTable.fnClose(this);
        }
    });

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {               
        $(this).removeClass('active');           

        var nTr = $(this)[0];                      
        oTable.fnClose(nTr);

    } else {                                        
        oTable.$('tr.row_selected').removeClass('active');      
        $(this).addClass('active');    

        var sOut = '<p><span class="badge"><i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i> ' + DataV + '</span> <span class="badge"><i class="fa fa-clock-o">' +
                   '</i> ' + OraV + '</span> <span class="badge"><i class="fa fa-tachometer"></i> ' + VelocitaV + ' km/h</span>' + 
                   '<a href="javascript:init(' + stringa + ')" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" style="float:right;">' + 
                   '<i class="fa fa-external-link"></i> Apri mezzo</a></p>' + '<span class="text-muted" id="Indirizzo' + aData[1] + '"></span>'
        oTable.fnOpen(nTr, sOut, 'details');  

});
```

The problem is that when I click a second time on the line, and then to close it , it will not close ! I noticed in debugging the function is repeated n times, ie how many times I've reworked the page , so if I reworked the page for twice the procedure is repeated twice, if I rework the page is repeated three times in three pre- times etcetera . As if I click on another row the first closes and reopens the other .

How do I run the procedure for closing the line to click a second time ?

Comment: What is `"sDom": '<"top"f>rt',` ?

Comment: Just a hunch but does it work if you use event delegation?
 `$("#archivio tbody").on('click', 'tr', function (e) {`

Comment: I forgot to write that I use for ASP.Net MVC and I wish it were not for that ....

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I defined the function into one that drew the table and was therefore called for all the times that the function was called. So I defined a variable and did an initial inspection:

**if ((states == null) | | (states =='')) {
     states = $ ("#archive tbody"). on ('click', 'tr', function (e) {**

Thank you all. 
dave